# Saving and updating high scores with Sprite Kit swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to save and update a high score with swift and sprite kit but my code seems to not work. Here is a picture of the code. Could some one help?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post an image of your code. Please post the actual code into your question (and be sure you format it properly). And explain what problem you are having. Again, put this in the question (do not post this info as comments).

Comment: Do what rmaddy said. Also, you have an obvious typo: "deafults". Please debug your code before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several errors in your code, most notably that you seem to be resetting your saved high score to zero every time. Try something like this:

```
if defaults.objectForKey("highScore") == nil {
        defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highScore")
    } else {
        if score > defaults.integerForKey("highScore") {
            defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highScore")
        }
    }
```

You'll have to tweak the above code to suit your particular purpose and make sure that all the variables are suitably defined and set, but this is my standard method for checking and setting a NSUserDefaults high score and it works for me.

Actually, I just thought of an even shorter syntax:

```
if defaults.objectForKey("highScore") == nil || score > defaults.integerForKey("highScore") {
    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highScore")
}
```